# How to dynamically sort columns in Sortable tableview library?

Tags: android, tableview

I am using Sortable TableView library to create the table structure with the sorting feature. The library is as below:

https://github.com/ISchwarz23/SortableTableView

I have the JSON response in which I am getting headers and body of table. In that I populated headers and body in the table:

```
String[] myarray = new String[goalData.getTableheaderList().size()];

for (int i = 0; i < goalData.getTableheaderList().size(); i++) {

    myarray[i] = goalData.getTableheaderList().get(i).getName();

    if (goalData.getTableheaderList().get(i).isSort()) {

        int index = GoalsUtils.getIndex(goalData.getTableBodyList().get(0),
                goalData.getTableheaderList().get(i).getKey());

        setColumnComparator(i, TableComparator.getBodyComparator(index));

    }
}
```

As you can see I have used array to display headers and body is also displayed in different code in same manner. Also I have used Column Comparator in the loop itself to sort the columns according to data. This is my Table comparator class:

```
public final class TableComparator {

private static int headerIndex;

private TableComparator() {
    //no instance
}

public static Comparator<List<TableBody>> getBodyComparator(int index) {
    headerIndex = index;
    return new BodyComparator();
}

private static class BodyComparator implements Comparator<List<TableBody>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(final List<TableBody> body1, final List<TableBody> body2) {
        return body1.get(headerIndex).getValue().compareTo(body2.get(headerIndex).getValue());
    }
}
```

}

Now the issue is that I am always getting headerIndex fixed in above code. My question how to get it dynamically. Does anyone know how to detect header click in this library or how we can get headerIndex different all the time the header column clicks? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you are using a third part library, you should ask questions related to its usage on its own comunity or suport service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve my issue. So I am posting the answer if anyone needs. So I was using headerIndex to sort the column. In the library, The columnComparator class uses static methods for its sorting purpose. I achieved dynamic sorting with following code:

```
    String[] headerArray = new String[headers.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
        int index = GoalsUtils.getIndex(body.get(0), headers.get(i).getKey());
        if (headers.get(i).isSort()) {
            setColumnComparator(i, new TableComparator(index));
        }
    }
```

and My TableComparator class as follows:

```
public final class TableComparator implements Comparator<List<TableBody>> {

private int headerIndex;

public TableComparator(int index) {
    headerIndex = index;
}

@Override
public int compare(final List<TableBody> body1, final List<TableBody> body2) {
    return body1.get(headerIndex).getValue().compareTo(body2.get(headerIndex).getValue());
}
```

}

Happy coding!